# How to move/pan the svg to a certain position?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg, transform

I am able to pan/move the whole SVG in D3.js with a mouse movement with the code below. Now, I wish to do this transformation without the mouse, that means to shift the SVG to a certain (X, Y) position. I know how to do this with DOM elements but I am not sure how to do this with an SVG?

```
var svg = d3.select("#svg")
    .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
            svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
        })).append("g");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `transform` feature.

```
<svg transform="translate(220,200)" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GdCcA/1201/